# My headphones are not playing voices, but only the music

Tags: windows-8, audio

I'm using stereo headphones on Windows 8. When I play songs I can't hear them normally.  Instead I'm only able to hear just "blurry" music, so I can barely hear the voices singing.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bad sound quality of 3.5mm headphone with mic on laptop](http://superuser.com/questions/271943/bad-sound-quality-of-3-5mm-headphone-with-mic-on-laptop)

Comment: You are describing "distortion".  This can have many causes, defective headphones being the most likely, but damage to the driver circuitry in the computer is another.  And the audio software that drives the circuitry is pretty complex and could be mucked up somehow.  First make sure the headphones are OK, then make sure that you actually are plugged into the right output -- if there are headphone, speaker, and/or line outputs, make sure you're first trying headphone, and if that's not working try one of the others.  And note that full size "earmuff" headphones may overload the outputs.

Comment: Did you tried with any other headphone?

Answer (score 9):

When my own headphones did this, i simply pulled them out a little but not completely. When they're pushed in completely voices were muffled, but after pulling it out and putting it in securely but not completely, it worked.

Comment: Brilliant!!! Thank you. I thought, I am loosing it.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure your system is configured for *Stereo Output*. This sounds a lot like the system is directing voices to a center channel, while your headphones are getting the front or side L/R channels of a surround-sound configuration (which would have muted voices).

Answer (score 6):

If they are connected via a cable (aka, not wireless), it's very likely that the cable just got pulled a bit and therefore the connection isn't good, so some audio doesn't "pass". Try to reconnect the headphones, and if this doesn't help, try to connect them to another port.
If the problem still exists, try to:

- Restart your PC
- Check of the headphones are broken: the best way to do it is to test them with another computer. Also try using **another** pair of headphones on the computer you're experiencing this problem with.
- Re-install the audio drivers (if you have come far to this step, please give us the system specs so I will be able to find the relevant drivers). *Driver problem is not very likely in the situation*

Comment: I'd add that it would be good to test with another pair of headphones to see if the error is with the interface or the phones...

Comment: Good idea, I'll edit my answer in a minute

Comment: I know this will sound stupid (maybe) but since I last put in some earbuds which are meant for music and not voices, this might be the problem. It's happened before and I don't know how I fixed it, it might've been my windows 7 computer though.

Comment: Try to use another headphones/earbuds/whatever on this PC. The problem you are describing fits with unstable connection caused by "kind of" broken headphones, or a sound port (probably plug 3.5mm) that was really wear out.

Comment: I've done that, it seems to do the same :/

Answer (score 0):

My sound driver had a tab called "Sonic Focus" by "VirageLogic".

I unchecked "Enable sonic focus" and the problem went away.